# Rails how to automatic check if a link is broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possible to automatic check if a link is broken?
What is the best solution (Screenscraping or other)

Comment: You mean other than by clicking on it? Or are you looking for an automated solutions? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Yes I mean other than clicking on it. An automatic solution for checking links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which is an automated testing framework.
You could also try [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) which is a monitoring application (daemon).  Sometimes I just use that service to check if a particular website or link is up.  You can set it to check periodically.